# Which is grammatically correct - "define" or "to define"?

Tags: grammar, present-simple

I am writing a description for a video. I want to know which of the following is more correct:

1. The next step is ***to*** define the cross section of the member.
2. The next step is define the cross section of the member

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Number 1 is correct because you want to use it as an infinitive verb. Here is a brief explanation with some examples:

> There are several possible ways to use infinitive verbs. You can use
>   them:
>
> 1. as the subject of a sentence – *To err is human; to forgive, divine*.
> 2. like an adjective or adverb phrase that expresses purpose or intent – *My instructions are to press this button every hour*.
> 3. following an indirect object – *He told me to give this to you*.
> 4. following certain other verbs - [source](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/infinitive-verb.html#FXmKtlWU6oC8ZoyO.99)

Comment: Need more explanation. "Define" is also an infinitive, and (2) is technically correct but unusual. The web site linked to under "source" is strange: it doesn't explain "infinitive", even in the section titled "Defining an Infinitive Verb".

Answer (score 8):

Number 1 is correct.  The only way you can make 2 correct is if you were reading a list of instructions such as:

1. Get milk.
2. Get eggs.

And then the person reads the list and says: "Step one is 'get milk', step two is 'get eggs'".

Answer (score 6):

#1 is correct.  #2 could be correct if you change "define" to "defining".  "Defining" is a gerund noun, and a noun works fine here.